# VHDL Assert - Concurrent statements

Tags: concurrency, vhdl, assert

I am trying to use VHDL assertions. In my design, I have written the assert statement directly in the DUT because I want to monitor internal signal. And since my assertion is concurrent with the instructions, the simulator raises an report almost at each input change.

I give you a minimal working example below (a simple adder). It is not my actual design, just an illustration of my problem.

How can I modify my code so that assertions are not triggered at unwanted times ? No synthesis constraints here.

Thank you in advance !

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.std_logic_arith.all;

entity Full_Adder is
   port( X, Y, Cin : in std_logic;
         sum, Cout : out std_logic);
end Full_Adder;
 
architecture bhv of Full_Adder is

signal s_sum : std_logic:='0'; -- to be used in the assert
signal s_Cout : std_logic:='0'; -- to be used in the assert

begin

   s_sum <= (X xor Y) xor Cin;
   s_Cout <= (X and (Y or Cin)) or (Cin and Y);
   sum<=s_sum;
   Cout<=s_Cout;

   assert (s_sum =((X xor Y) xor Cin)) report "Erreur de somme" severity note;
   assert (s_Cout = ((X and (Y or Cin)) or (Cin and Y))) report "Erreur de retenue" severity note;

end bhv;
```

Testbench :

```
Library IEEE;
USE IEEE.Std_logic_1164.all;
entity tb_fulladder is
end tb_fulladder;
 
architecture behavioral of tb_fulladder is
 component Full_Adder
   port( 
   X, Y, Cin : in std_logic;  
  sum, Cout : out std_logic
  );  
 end component; 

 signal A,B,Cin: std_logic:='0';
 signal S,Cout: std_logic;

begin   
 structural_adder: Full_Adder port map 
   (
    X => A,
    Y => B,
    Cin => Cin,
    sum => S,
    Cout => Cout 
   );
   
process
  begin
   A <= '0';
   B <= '0';
   Cin <= '0';
   wait for 100 ns;
   A <= '0';
   B <= '0';
   Cin <= '1';
   wait for 100 ns;   
   A <= '0';
   B <= '1';
   Cin <= '0';
   wait for 100 ns;
   A <= '0';
   B <= '1';
   Cin <= '1';
   wait for 100 ns;
   A <= '1';
   B <= '0';
   Cin <= '0';
   wait for 100 ns;
   A <= '1';
   B <= '0';
   Cin <= '1';
   wait for 100 ns;
   A <= '1';
   B <= '1';
   Cin <= '0';
   wait for 100 ns;   
   A <= '1';
   B <= '1';
   Cin <= '1';
   wait for 100 ns;   
  end process;
      
end behavioral;
```

Comment: Just to be totally clear, the problem is not that the assertions don't work, but that they are triggerred a lot more times than you expect. Is that correct? If so, try to make this more clear in the question.

Comment: You are right. I edited my question, hope it is clearer now.

Comment: You need to account for the delta cycle delay in the signal update for s_sum and s_Cout. For s_sum: `assert s_sum = ((X'delayed(0 ns) xor Y'delayed(0 ns)) xor Cin'delayed(0 ns)) report "Erreur de somme" severity note;` or `process begin wait on s_sum; assert s_sum = (X xor Y xor Cin) report "Erreur de somme" severity NOTE; end process;`  XOR is commutative (you have unneeded parentheses). Conditions are syntactically distinguishable and don't require outer parentheses. A concurrent assertion statement is elaborated to a passive process statement containing a sequential assertion statement.

Comment: Adding delta cycle delay works fine. But the ```wait on``` instruction is not a valid option: if a change in the inputs does not change the output, the assertion is not evaluated.
The last thing that is not working correctly (but I think I'll have to live with it) is at the initialization, when an assertion is triggered whereas it shouldn't.
Anyway, many thanks !!

Answer (score 0):

You can code your assertions in a process structure that its sensitivity list can be used for control signals like followings;

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.std_logic_arith.all;

entity Full_Adder is
   port( X, Y, Cin : in std_logic;
         sum, Cout : out std_logic);
end Full_Adder;
 
architecture bhv of Full_Adder is

signal s_sum : std_logic:='0'; -- to be used in the assert
signal s_Cout : std_logic:='0'; -- to be used in the assert

begin

   s_sum <= (X xor Y) xor Cin;
   s_Cout <= (X and (Y or Cin)) or (Cin and Y);
   sum<=s_sum;
   Cout<=s_Cout;

   process(<related signals>) begin
      assert (s_sum =((X xor Y) xor Cin)) report "Erreur de somme" severity note;
      assert (s_Cout = ((X and (Y or Cin)) or (Cin and Y))) report "Erreur de retenue" severity note;
   end process;

end bhv;
```

By the way, you can use the same piece of code in testbench, but you may not receive internal design signals this way.

Good luck.