# VHDL concurrent assertions and delta cycles

Tags: vhdl, hdl, modelsim

I am trying to use VHDL concurrent assertions in order to verify that a signal correctly drives another. As they should be directly connected at some times (no latching), I want to use a **concurrent** assertion of the following form :

`assert (driver_sig = driven_sig) or not check_sigs report "Error" severity error;`

Here, `check_sigs` simply serves as a flag that masks the assertion when the signals are not connected.

However, this does not work in this form, because it takes some amount of delta cycles to update the driven signal (about 10), and the assertion triggers an error in these delta cycles.

There was a solution given in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64914356/vhdl-assert-concurrent-statements) in which we add `'delayed(0 ns)` to the driver signal in order to take the value after a delta cycle. However, this only works if the number of delta cycles between the signals is only one, so I still have the problem, just one delta cycle later (when viewing from time deltas mode in modelsim).

Is there a way to adapt this solution for any amount of delta cycles ? Which means we would delay the checked signals until the last delta cycle of a timestep, instead of checking at every delta. (or, once per timestep, beginning or end)

Answer (score 0):

A one liner in VHDL actually infers a process that is sensitive to all signals in that one liner. So why not simply wrap the assertion in a process that is only sensitive to the later signal?
Assuming that driven_sig is the one you want to check, use:

```vhdl
process(driven_sig, check_sigs)
begin
  assert (driver_sig = driven_sig) or not check_sigs report "Error" severity error;
end process;
```

this way it only performs the assertion when `driven_sig` or `check_sigs` changes, but not the `driver_sig`.

Comment: Thank you, can you think of a reason why this solution was not recommended in the post I referenced ? This one looks more robust

Comment: In that case the delay was only a single delta, so a 1 delta delayed version of the signal was acceptable. It is not possible in VHDL to specify a number of deltas to delay a signal, only a timestep. So here, if you know the `driven_sig` is always delayed, and is the change you actually want to check on, this answer seems appropriate.

Comment: I see. Yes, your answer seems more appropriate in any case, it's the one I was talking about.